# How to capture video from iphone app?

Tags: objective-c, ios4, video-capture

I open the video mode while press the record button. Then i can capture the video. After capture the video record has to be stop. Now below the screen display retake button in the left side and use button in the right side. Here is my problem started, If I press use button, How can I save the video different name in a specific folder?. And How can I access that videos from that specific folder?.

Please give idea with sample code to resolve this problem.

Thanks in advance,

Senthilkumar

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will have to implement to become the delegate of the `UIImagePickerController` object and implement `imagePickerController:didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:` like this –

```
- (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info {
    // This is the URL where the movie is stored (in the tmp directory)
    NSURL *movieURL = [info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerMediaURL];

    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
    NSString *filePath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"movie.mov"]; // You will have to vary this.
    NSURL *fileURL = [NSURL URLWithString:filePath];

    NSError *error;
    if ( [[NSFileManager defaultManager] moveItemAtURL:movieURL toURL:fileURL error:&error] ) {    
        NSLog(@"Error copying: %@", [error localizedDescription]);
    }

    [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}
```

Comment: hai deepak, thanks for given the idea, but this is not work. if we are in capture mode. the image save in the nsdata format. same as here what we use?. in the image [myfilemanagername writedata:nsdataname]; like that what we want to use the video file save time.

Comment: Are we talking about images or videos here?

Comment: we have problem on save the video in a folder